# SNI support in ruby's net/http if there is no route to hostname

Tags: ruby, ssl, sni

I am writing a integration test code for a project and it sets up a new secure virtual host at a server. The server supports SNI. However, as the testing code is meant to run in development environment, so the DNS record for the host name isn't properly set up. So in order to check if the right certificate is returned, with curl I have to do this

```
curl -i --cacert sample_ca.crt --resolve example.com:443:1.2.3.4 https://example.com/
```

or via openssl utility

```
openssl s_client -connect 1.2.3.4:443 -servername example.com
```

I managed to find references to sort of reproduce the use case in ruby as follows

```
context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
context.ca_file = 'sample_ca.crt'
context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

tcp_client = TCPSocket.new('1.2.3.4', 443)
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_client, context)
ssl_client.hostname = 'example.com'
ssl_client.connect

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_client.peer_cert)
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read(''sample_pkey.key))

if cert.check_private_key(pkey) then
  ssl_client.print "GET #{uri} HTTP/1.1\r\n"
  ssl_client.print "Host: example.com\r\n\r\n"
  header, body = ssl_client.read.split("\r\n\r\n")
else
  header, body = ['', '']
end

ssl_client.sysclose
tcp_client.close
```

I wanted to implement this with purely net/http initially, however unless I get DNS set up properly for example.com (I don't have access to the DNS settings, so I cheated by editing my host file), it wouldn't work regardless how I tried. Considering I am relatively new to ruby, I wonder if there is a way of doing it with just net/http?

Comment: Can you run it against a self signed certificate using localhost? You can even set up a private PKI for testing and certify a cert for localhost.

Comment: not sure, will have to try, but this doesn't emulate the environment that I am hoping to replicate (:

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it but looking at this, it looks like one has to monkey patch `TCPSocket::open` such that it resolves the address given into something else than it otherwise would do. There is no way to intercept and change the `TCPSocket` object before it is passed to SSL. See source of `HTTP#connect` method.
I think monkey patching `TCPSocket` is a very bad idea though and only to be done for non-production testing.